# Empty row in ng-option still apears in select menu

Tags: html, angularjs, json, ng-options, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Hi I have select menu that should not have empty row, this is my code in AngularJS

```
    $scope.GetAllSnimateljiBaseInfo = function () {

    $http.get(serviceBase + "GetAllSnimateljiBaseInfo", { timeout: 6000 })
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.snimatelji = response;
        $scope.snimatelji.splice(0, 0, { "IDsnimatelj": 0, "Ime": "", "Prezime": "" });
        $scope.selectedSnimateljInfilterVideoKlip = $scope.snimatelji[0];
    })
     .error(function (response, status) {
         if (status == 401) {
             $state.go('/');

         }
         else {
             alert(response.Message);
         }
     });
};
```

this is HTML code

```
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3">Snimatelj:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-options="column as column.Ime +' '+ column.Prezime for column in snimatelji" ng-model="selectedSnimateljInfilterVideoKlip">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But select menu looks like this

[image]

As you can see I have two empty menu options instead of one ?

Where is my mistake , any help please ?

Regards

Comment: you need to use "track by <your id attribute>", because the option comparation doesn't recognize by entire record. If you need more help, you can create a jsbin or plunker to show for us.

Answer (score 0):

By default one empty row will be there for angular select. The additional empty row is because you have specified

```
<option value=""></option>
```

in select tag- remove that.
If you would like to remove the default empty row as well, then set 
    $scope.selectedSnimateljInfilterVideoKlip =         $scope.snimatelji[0]
 or use ng-init to achieve the same.

Comment: @Zvonimir Tokic - updated the answer; html got escaped last day as I missed to put it as code block. Removing the manually set option tag will remove one blank item. To remove the default blank item, the idea is to set default value to the model.As you said you are alredy doing it; could you just try printing selectedSnimateljInfilterVideoKlip in html to verify this value is set fine?